# Liferay : How to send parameter using URL?

Tags: java, liferay-6

I am use Liferay 6.2 CA4 and Tomcat 7. I want to send parameter in url using `portlet:renderURL` but i have 2 link and each link have a difference value. So i tried to create like this but it's not work well.
**JSP :**

```
<a class="button cta button-info" href="
          <portlet:renderURL var="renderInquiryUrl">
            <portlet:param name="action" value="renderInquiry" />
            <portlet:param name="id" value="1" />
          </portlet:renderURL>
">A</a>
<a class="button cta button-info" href="
          <portlet:renderURL var="renderInquiryUrl2">
            <portlet:param name="action" value="renderInquiry" />
            <portlet:param name="id" value="2" />
          </portlet:renderURL>
">B</a>
```

**JAVA :**

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=renderAttendanceClass")
    public String renderAttendanceClass(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model) throws Exception{
        String param = request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(param);
        return "attendanceclass";
    }
```

> When i click that link, it's just reload that page

Can anyone help me, how to send param in the same renderURL ?

Answer (score 0):

The var must be different for each Portlet URL you are using the same  variable

Comment: yeah it's work, but when i click that link there's nothing happen. It's like refresh that page, not displaying 'param'. can u help me ?

Comment: In the code you have post the action parameter is different from that in the java code so you are not calling that method

Answer (score 0):

For the first link:

**JSP:**

```
<portlet:renderURL var="renderInquiryUrl">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="renderInquiry" />
    <portlet:param name="id" value="1" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<a class="button cta button-info" href="<%=renderInquiryUrl%>">A</a>
```

**Java:**

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=renderInquiry")
    public String renderInquiry(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model) throws Exception{
        String param = request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(param);
        ...
    }
```

For the second link:

**JSP:**

```
<portlet:renderURL var="renderInquiryUrl2">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="renderInquiry2" />
    <portlet:param name="id" value="1" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<a class="button cta button-info" href="<%=renderInquiryUrl2%>">B</a>
```

**Java:**

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=renderInquiry2")
    public String renderInquiry2(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model) throws Exception{
        String param = request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(param);
        ...
    }
```